# Listbox y archivos txt tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

soy relativamente nuevo en este mundo y necesito que los datos que introduzca en un listbox, se agreguen a un archivo .txt previamente creado. Hasta ahora sólo puedo agregar el último elemento introducido en el listbox de esta manera:

```
def finish():
    with open('Llamado_clientes.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(nombre_cliente.get())
```

Y luego importar esos datos a otro listbox de otro archivo.
Muchas gracias, si algo no se entiende, puedo explicarlo mejor

Answer (score 0):

holaaa, me puedes mostrar de que manera se agregan tus datos a la listbox?

aunque te dejo una idea:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
def save_data():
    # Obtén todos los elementos del ListBox
    items = listbox.get(0, tk.END)

    # Verifica si hay elementos en el ListBox
    if not items:
        messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "No hay elementos para guardar.")
        return

    # Guarda los elementos en el archivo de texto
    with open('Llamado_clientes.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines('\n'.join(items))

    # Muestra un mensaje de éxito
    messagebox.showinfo("Éxito", "Datos guardados correctamente.")
```